# Routing not done in controller redirect Symfony2 - dynamic routing

Tags: symfony, routes

here is the context of the question: I want to build a multi-site installation of Symfony2. Having on one side the admin and the content types which are common for every site but a differenciation of the templates for each site

Hence, I would need routing specific per site visited. Let's say we have 2 sites sub1.site.com & sub2.site.com, for the same pattern '/' I would like to be able to route differently the request for each subsite.

1st solution tested: use the 'host' of the routing system as in here ([Host routing in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html#component-routing-host-imported)). 
Implemented like that it didn't worked

```
routingFirstSite:
    resource: "@BundleName/Resources/config/routing1.yml"
    host: "sub1.site.com"
    prefix: /

routingSecondSite:
    resource: "@BundleName/Resources/config/routing2.yml"
    host: "sub2.site.com"
    prefix: /                             ==>*(added after 1st comment)
```

==> This solution doesn't work, it loads the second regarless of the host used...

2nd solution put in place : use a dynamic routing upon listening to the kernel.request event as in the following solution : [Symfony custom/dynamic router](http://marcjschmidt.de/blog/2013/11/30/symfony-custom-dynamic-router.html).

It works perfectly. I then put included directly the routing of the admin into the routing.yml file and have the "sites" routing loaded up dynamically.

BUT

upon the submit of any form to create/edit/delete any content in the site, the admin controller have the following return which is giving an error 500 (can't find the route 'index')

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
```

(needless to say that the 'index' route is defined in all of the sub_routing.yml files for all sites).

to understand what was in the request to be sure that I was properly arriving, I modified to the following:

```
var_dump($this->getRequest()->attributes->all());
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
```

And by miracle this is working, I'm redirected to the index of the site!

My question is then : What's the mechanism at stake here? Why is it not working in the first place and well in the second? What should I do to have it working in the first situation?

thanks a lot for your time,

Comment: your first solution should work fine, maybe it´s because you missed the prefix in routingSecondSite

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's an error of copy-paste as the prefix argument existed in my routing.yml file... (I've updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

in my project i always added a requirement to match host like this :

and i use a variable and a parameter in parameters.yml eg %your_host%

```
routingFirstSite:
    resource: "@BundleName/Resources/config/routing1.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host: "{your_host}"
    requirements:
        your_host: %your_host%


routingFirstSite:
    resource: "@BundleName/Resources/config/routing2.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host: "{your_second_host}"
    requirements:
        your_second_host: %your_second_host%
```

and in parameters.yml you have like:

```
your_host: sub1.site.com
your_second_host: sub2.site.com
```

without quotes
you should give it a try, hould work, if not pls tell which symfony2 version youre running

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried it and after a clear of the cache, it's unfortunately not working. I'm working on Symfony 2.5.7

Comment: Hello, this all situation seems weird... Is there maybe another setting I've forgotten to put somewhere other than in the routing.yml? (I've tried with and without quotes)